# How to access linux user directory from tomcat webserver

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, webserver

I have deployed my j2ee webapplication in tomcat(running in Ubuntu server 14.04). Ubuntu server has some users ie. user1, user2, user3, public(with sudo rights). Now these users needs to access folders in their home directory remotely(using Web UI from webapplication). I don't know which api to use or to implement it. 
**I will like to explain by example.**
1. If I am a normal user of ubuntu server with credential i.e. username - user1 and password- 12345. Now I would like to fill these credentials in login page of webapplication deployed in that server and would like to get list of directories present in my home directory of server. Also, I will like open/edit files present.
2. If user1 belongs to some group then how to get access of all the resources present there.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do this, then Tomcat itself must be running as a superuser and you open all sorts of security holes.

Comment: Have a look at the [WebDav protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). The Apache webserver already has modules for that, but there might be Java implementations, too.

Comment: Hi Nick, I think if tomcat is running as super user then there will be no need of authentication by user, it can directly access all users data. It will be a big security hole in it. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I will look into WebDav protocol and will get back to you.